# How to find the probability distribution function from the Moment generating function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given that you know the moment distribution function $M_{x}(t)$, for example, $M_{x}(t)=a\exp(b\,t)$, is it possible to define the probability distribution function $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

The probability density function (PDF) is the Laplace transform of the Moment Generating Function (MGF). for example:

if the distribution is an exponential distribution i.e. $f_x(x)=\lambda \exp(-\lambda x), \quad x \geq 0$ and zero otherwise, we can calculate its inverse Laplace transform to yield the MGF:
\begin{equation}
M_x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp \left ( tx \right ) \lambda \exp \left ( -\lambda x \right ) dx = \\
\lambda \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp (t-\lambda) dx = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}.
\end{equation}

In your example you have to first make sure that this is a valid MGF (i.e. its Laplace transform yields a valid PDF).

Comment: Could demonstrate this mathematically please. So let $M_{x}(t)=a\,\exp(bt)$ what will $f(x)$ be? Thank You.